# Discord Py slash command in cogs

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am using the newest version of discord py and python. I wanted to make a custom bot with slash commands in cogs. For now my bot already has some cogs command but now slash commands thee commands work perfectly fine. I looked up some things and came up with this but as you can guess its not working. so far i wrote this code in my cog:

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands

class Slash(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client: commands.Bot):
        self.client = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("Slash cog loaded")

    @commands.command()
    async def sync(self, ctx) -> None:
        fmt = await ctx.client.tree.sync(guild=ctx.guild)
        await ctx.send(f"Synced {len(fmt)} commands.")

    @app_commands.command(name="slash", description="test slash command")
    async def ping(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        bot_latency = round(self.client.latency * 1000)
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"Pong! {bot_latency} ms.")


async def setup(client):
    await client.add_cog(Slash(client), guilds=[discord.Object(id="HEREISMYSERVERID")])
```

I also wrote this code in my main file:

````
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from itertools import cycle
import os
import asyncio
import json


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents.all(), application_id=MYAPPPLICATIONID)

bot_status = cycle(["Secret Things...","cooking"])

@tasks.loop(seconds=18000)
async def change_status():
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(next(bot_status)))

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Success: Bot is connected to Discord")
    change_status.start()




async def load():
    for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
        if filename.endswith("py"):
            await client.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")

async def main():
    async with client:
        await load()
        await client.start("MYTOKEN")

asyncio.run(main())```
I have also a bunch of normal cogs these work perfectly fine. also in my console i see that this slash cog was loaded. But when i try to use !sync nothing happens can someone please help me with this
````

Answer (score 2):

**You need to sync slash command in main file.**

```
@client.command(name="sync") 
async def sync(ctx):
    synced = await client.tree.sync()
    print(f"Synced {len(synced)} command(s).")
```

Discord don't sync slash command when you run this bot, so you need to sync every time you create a new command or fix bug.

After run the bot, you can use the sync command and wait for discord to sync slash command.

Answer (score 1):

The docs for `add_cog` say this about the `guilds` kwarg:

> If the cog is an application command group, then this would be the guilds where the cog group would be added to. If not given then it becomes a global command instead.

Your cog is not an application command group (it's a regular cog), so this doesn't do anything. As a result, your slash command is registered as a global one. This means that syncing to the guild (`sync(guild=...)`) does nothing, as the command isn't registered to that guild.

You can either use [`app_commands.guilds`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=app_commands#discord.app_commands.guilds) to add one specific command to a guild, or create a [`GroupCog`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=groupcog#discord.ext.commands.GroupCog) instead of a regular cog to do it for the entire cog.