# Am not able to use both command and slash command within a cog for Discord.py

Tags: python, discord

I am working with discord.py and am trying to make a command available as both a normal command and a slash command. When running my code, it seems that only one of the two options works (either or) and never both together. For example, sometimes the !ping works and sometimes the /ping works, but they don't both work at the same time and I would like both options to be available. What can I change to fix this issue?

This is my code for the cog:

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands

class Ping(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
    
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("Ping.py is loaded!")
    
    @commands.command()
    async def ping(self, ctx):
        bot_latency = round(self.bot.latency * 1000)

        await ctx.send(f"Pong! {bot_latency} ms.")
    
    @app_commands.command(name = "ping", description = "Returns ping to the server")
    async def ping(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        bot_latency = round(self.bot.latency * 1000)

        await interaction.response.send_message(f"Pong! {bot_latency} ms.", ephemeral = False)

async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(Ping(bot))
```

This is my main bot function if it is of any help:

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import pathlib

#Importing token/api keys
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os

def run_discord_bot():

    load_dotenv()

    #Discord token
    TOKEN = os.getenv("discord_bot_token")

    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!", intents = discord.Intents.all())

    #Load in Cogs
    @bot.event
    async def on_ready():
        print("Bot is up and running")

        try:
            synced = await bot.tree.sync()
            print(f"Synced {len(synced)} command(s)")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
    
    async def load():
        cogs_path = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent / "cogs"
        for filename in cogs_path.iterdir():
            if filename.suffix == ".py":
                await bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename.stem}")
    
    async def main():
        async with bot:
            await load()
            await bot.start(TOKEN)
    
    asyncio.run(main())
```

I have tried different iterations of slash commands and none seem to work and I am really confused as to how to make both of them work together and can not seem to find how to fix the problem.

Comment: maybe you should rewrite `on_message` and replace `/` with `!` - this way `Bot` will see both commands as  `!ping`. OR maybe you should rewrite `Bot` to check both `prefixes`

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75453339/discord-py-slash-command-in-cogs